# On the graph lables for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to generate the right side graph. I would like to create labels as shown in the left graph and x-intercept value for the vertical line.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ggplot(spss) + geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, ULCI), linetype="dashed", size = 1) + 
geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, Effect), color = "red", size = 1) + 
geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, LLCI),linetype="dashed", size = 1,show.legend = TRUE) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(0.78), linetype="dashed", show.legend = TRUE, size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi OP - can you post your dataset, `spss`, please?  Preferably, copy and paste the output of the function `dput(spss)` into the body of your question (formatted as code).  Thanks!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rV596I5Rtylqn_2ovd2zxCu_FsceTqei?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easiest to construct an extra little data frame to plot the labels:

```
labs <- data.frame(x = c(-1, rep(spss$ZIdeal[nrow(spss)], 3)) + 0.2,
                   y = c(1, spss$ULCI[nrow(spss)], spss$Effect[nrow(spss)],
                         spss$LLCI[nrow(spss)]),
                   labs =c(paste("When Idealism is 0.78 or more SD above mean, the",
                                 "simple slope is no longer significant", sep = "\n"),
                            "95% upper limit", "Point Estimate", "95% lower limit"))
          
ggplot(spss) + geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, ULCI), linetype="dashed", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, Effect), color = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(ZIdeal, LLCI),linetype="dashed", size = 1,show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(0.78), linetype="dashed", show.legend = TRUE, size = 1) +
  geom_label(data = labs, aes(x, y, label = labs), hjust = 0, label.size = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2.5, 3.5)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This serves the purpose. But the code is difficult to understand.  Is there any package available so that xx_label(95% upper limit, position = END) like adding lables.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS the code is just telling R the x and y locations of where the labels should be based on the data. The problem with `xx_label(95% upper limit, position = END)` is that you don't have an object called "95% upper limit", so R wouldn't know which line you were talking about. It would have to be `spss$UCLI, END`. But there is no object called END, so you need to tell R what END means, by doing `spss$UCLI[nrow(spss)]` . I guess it would be possible to write a function to make it easy to do exactly what you want, but your exact requirements aren't general enough to warrant a package.